# Etymology of "minniebush"?

Tags: etymology

I was playing a spelling game and got this word. I tried looking it up on etymonline.com but I didn't get any search results? I assume it is from combining two English words, but I was wondering if anyone could produce a more specific answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [minniebush](http://www.duke.edu/~cwcook/trees/mepi.html) is a type of shrub, found in some parts of the East Coast of the United States. Its Latin name is *Menziesia pilosum*, and it looks like this:

[image]

The etymology of the name, from [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minniebush) is:

> minnie- (irreg. fr. Archibald Menzies †1842 Scot. botanist) + bush

Since the plant was found by the botanist Archibald Menzies, both the scientific and common names for it are derived from his name.

Comment: Given that Menzies is pronounced 'mingis', how is *Menziesia* pronounced?  Is it *Mingisia*?

Comment: @z7sg: I'm not a botanist, but Merriam Webster says that the pronunciation is \menˈzēzh(ē)ə\.